# Error when enumerate differently a special theorem

Tags: errors

I have the following code in the beginning of the file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel} % Kieli: Suomi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeindex
\newtheoremstyle{special}
    {\topsep}
    {\topsep}
    {\itshape}
    {}
    {\bfseries}
    {$^{\bm\ast}$\kern-1.5pt.}%  Punctuation after theorem head % <-- new
    {.5em}
    {}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lause}[thm]{Lause}
\newtheorem{huom}[thm]{Huomautus}
\theoremstyle{special}
\newtheorem{spthm}[thm]{Teoreema}

\newtheorem{thm*}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{dem*}{De Morganin lait}
```

After that, in a document, I have

```
\begin{spthm}
This is a special theorem.
\end{spthm}
```

Now the Texmaker 5.0.3 and pdflatex complains:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> $^{\bm 
                       \ast }$\kern -1.5pt.
l.483 T
       his is a special theorem.
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I have cleaned a bit your code by to delete `\usepackage{amsfonts}` and I have improved a strange `\bm` command without that you use the `bm` package. I have used this `{$\boldsymbol{^\ast}$\kern-1.5pt.}` and all your code works correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel} % Kieli: Suomi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeindex
\newtheoremstyle{special}
    {\topsep}
    {\topsep}
    {\itshape}
    {}
    {\bfseries}
    {$\boldsymbol{^\ast}$\kern-1.5pt.}%  Punctuation after theorem head % <-- new
    {.5em}
    {}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lause}[thm]{Lause}
\newtheorem{huom}[thm]{Huomautus}
\theoremstyle{special}
\newtheorem{spthm}[thm]{Teoreema}
\newtheorem{thm*}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{dem*}{De Morganin lait}

\begin{document}
\begin{spthm}
This is a special theorem.
\end{spthm}
\end{document}
```